# How to Secure a WebMethod in asp.net/Jquery

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I am using Jquery Ajax to call a WebMethod from aspx page.Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnshow").click(function () {
               $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "example.aspx/showData",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

code on aspx.cs page:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static List<LandmarkList> showData()
{
    LandmarkList ObjLL = new LandmarkList();
    return ObjLL.GetDataList();
}
```

My question is what is a professional way to secure this web method?what are possible methods of securing webmethods so that a user wont copy that url from client debugging tools and use it.

Note:These are open pages,user do nto need to be loged in for these pages.

**UPDATE:** I want to make it more difficult for someone to continue using my webservice without actually visiting my site.

Comment: If it is an open page that anyone can call without being logged in, then waht are you trying to secure it from?  In what fashion do you wish it to be secure?

Comment: Actually people can easily find from client side debuggers that what is the structure of that function,how many parameters are passing and then easily they can call that function.I do not want people to use this function.

Comment: But you *do* want people to be able to use the function since it is part of an open web page.  If you are worried about DOS attacks, etc then stuff can be done.  If you are worried about the information revealed by the function being available to others then you need to rethink the design of the whole application somewhat radically (e.g.. require some form of user authentication first).  For which people/in what situations should the use of the service be allowed and not allowed?

Comment: @Adam:My question is very simple,I do not want to allow users to use my methods outside my website.OR do not misuse it.For example in my code,if you just invoke this method with js "showData()",it will give you result

Comment: What about the first answer from this thread ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404925/can-someone-access-my-webmethods-from-outside-of-the-page), the one talking about one-time password/token.

Comment: I read that,but i am not sure how to do this?it will not be applicable if i am using jquery/Js or client side

Answer (score 0):

There is no showData() function in your code but yes anyone could simply call the example.aspx/showData url and get a response.

You can do stuff to try and ensure they are calling from your page.  At it's simplest you could simply check they already have loaded the page via checking (in your web service) for a session parameter (which you set when the page loads).  Or, for example, see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks.

However, without any form of authentication before loading the page and allowing the service call there I think that the value of any such security measures are dubious - you are giving yourself the illusion of security without actually having any.  Anyone who wants to call your service can simply script a load of the page followed by the call and monitor your results.  The web service is as open as the page calling it - and it's not meaningful to say "I've got this open web page but want to make sure it's only called in a certain way/by certain people".

You are safer, in my opinion, to simply treat the web service as open and not reveal anything there that you would not be comfortable putting on an open web page.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my comment about that was maybe not clear.  There is no showData() function callable as a function externally (e.g. in javascript) so I assumed you mean calling the /showData web service URL (which causes .net to call the showData() function in your .cs). Semantics really, was just checking that was what was meant.  The rest of the comment stands, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution in the world, but very easy and quick to implement-

Use Cloudflare > Firewall > Tools > Rate limiting > create custom rule to block visits more than a given frequency to differentiate between use and abuse